# How can I rearrange this table to another away laravel eloquent relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, html-table, eloquent

I used laravel hasmany relationship in my user model. I just want to convert my table like below (row to column):

[image]

To:

[image]

Here is my `User` model:

```
public function meal(){
        return $this->hasMany(Meal::class);
    }
```

My controller:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $members = User::all();
        return view('admin.meal')->with([
            'members' => $members,
        ]);
}
```

and @blade

```
 <table class="table table-striped @if(count($members)>7) table-responsive @endif ">


           <thead>
            <tr class="text-uppercase">
                {{--<th class="font-w700">Date</th>--}}
                @foreach($members as $member)
                    <th class="font-w700">{{str_limit($member->fname,5,'...')}}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($members as $member)
                <tr>
                    @foreach($member->meal as $meal)
                    <td><span class="font-w600">{{$meal->user_id}}</span></td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Could you further explain the relationship that you're after? What does a meal mean and how it is associated with the user?

Comment: every user has many meal .meal means like a user eat every day